# Calculating actual speed between two 2d coordinates in consecutive frames

Tags: python, image, math, image-processing

I am attempting to calculate the actual speed between frames based on pixel-shifting from two points of 2D co-ordinates.

The coordinates are stored in a manner such that `co_ordinates[frame_number][pixel_index][pixel_value_x][pixel_value_y]`

For example, this is how `frame_number=1` and `pixel_index=1` is shown when `co_ordinates[0][0]`

```
array([[113.        , 231.        ],
       [112.83630458, 230.73530376]])
```

Comment: I didn't quite catch your desire. Do you want to find the speed of a moving object in the image? If so, how is your object is positioned in front of the camera? Can you attach some sample image too?

Comment: Please just add at least two sample images to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code ought to be working as it is. You might want perhaps to calculate first the coordinates of the frame point-cloud barycenter, and infer the frame speed from *that*. This is faster and has the advantage of slightly reducing error propagation:

```
cx = 0;
cy = 0;
for point_number in range(0, number_of_points):
    cx = cx + co_ordinates[frame_number][point_number][0][0]
    cy = cy + co_ordinates[frame_number][point_number][0][1]
cx = cx / number_of_points;
cy = cy / number_of_points;
if frame_number > 0:
    distance = math.sqrt((cx-prevx)**2 + (cy-prevy)**2)
    # Calculate speed 
prevx = cx;
prevy = cy;
```

You might also want to calculate rotation between frames (so-called [registration](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2016_workshops/w17/papers/Ma_Fast_and_Accurate_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf) of [point clouds](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/cista/455/Lectures/Rigid3D3DCalculations.pdf)). A brute force approach would be to calculate the angle between each point and the barycenter, then the angle between that point and the new barycenter in the next frame, and average angles over all the points. **For rigid clouds**, this gives the same result as the quaternion approach.